# Custom autocomplete form and autosubmit

Tags: forms

I've added an autocomplete function for my views_exposed_form (a text input) using this tutorial and it works (https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/implementing-autocomplete-drupal-8-custom-callbacks-waliullah-khan).

I'd like to add a "submit on click" behaviour, so when I click on a value of the autocomplete it changes the value of the input and then submit the form.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Attaching below code:

**custom.module**

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function custom_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    if ($form['#id'] == "YOUR_FORM-ID") {
      $form['combine']['#autocomplete_route_name'] = 'custom.autocomplete';
      $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'custom/custom';
      $form_state->setCached(FALSE);
    }
  }
}
```

**custom.routing.yml**

```
custom.autocomplete:
  path: '/want/autocomplete'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\custom\Controller\WantAutoController::autocomplete'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

**custom.libraries.yml**

```
custom:
  version: 0
  js:
    js/custom.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

**js/custom.js**

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.custom = {
        attach: function (context) {
            $("#FIELD-ID").autocomplete({
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    if (ui.item) {
                        var itemLink = $(ui.item.label).attr('href');
                        window.location.href = itemLink;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
}(jQuery));
```

**src/Controller/WantAutoController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Returns tree responses for nodes.
 */
class WantAutoController extends ControllerBase {


  function autocomplete(Request $request) {
    $db_conn = \Drupal::database();
    $matches = [];
    $string = $request->query->get('q');
      $alias = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager');
      $db_conn = \Drupal::database();
      $query = $db_conn->select('node','n');
      $query->leftJoin('node_field_data', 'nfd', 'nfd.nid = n.nid');
      $query->fields('n');
      $query->fields('nfd',['title']);
      $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
      if ($results) {
        foreach ($results as $row) {
          $path = $alias->getAliasByPath('/node/' . $row->nid);
          $linkTonode = '<a href="' . $path . '">' . $row->title . '</a>';
          $matches[] = ['value' => $row->title, 'label' => $linkTonode];
        }
      }
    return new JsonResponse($matches);
  }

}
```

Here in the autocomplete we are building value with "a" tag. And while searching autocomplete field our autocomplete return with "a" tag also. We are also building **js** here to click on that value and redirect.

Comment: There are a few points to make about your JS. You should use the passed '$' variable rather than 'jQuery' as this helps to ensure your script can run on a page with multiple jQuery instances. The attach method will run after any AJAX updates to the DOM so you should use the 'context' variable in jQuery calls to restrict their scope. And it's also good practice to use the once() method in any actions on jQuery objects that only need to be done once, to ensure that is the case.